# Is there a limitation to what data type can be used as an index in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

If I create a simple `DataFrame` like this,

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({
...   'foo': ['A', 'B'],
...   'bar': ['1', '2']
... })
```

then I can use the first column of strings as an index:

```
>>> df1.set_index('foo').loc['A', 'bar']
'1'
```

Now, if the first column contains classes, `pandas` is still able to build a `DataFrame`,

```
>>> class A: pass
>>> class B: pass
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({
...   'foo': [A, B],
...   'bar': ['1', '2']
... })
```

but even though using the column as an index succeeds, using `loc` on it does not:

```
>>> df2.set_index('foo').loc[A, 'bar']
TypeError: A() takes no arguments
```

Note that classes `A` and `B` are hashable and can be used as `dict` keys:

```
>>> {A: '1', B: '2'}[A]
'1'
```

So what is happening here, what are the limits as the types that can be used for indexing a `DataFrame` and what could be a workaround?

Comment: Though I'm sure there is a logical reason behind what is going on, what purpose does it serve to push Pandas to edge cases it clearly wasn't designed for?

Comment: @piRSquared - In what way is pandas not designed to do this? A and B are classes, not instances, and things like less than won't work. So there may be a technical reason why this type of thing won't work. But I think that's what the question is about.... the why.

Comment: It seems like you editted out the traceback showing the stack trace. That's valuable information to include in hte question.

Comment: @tdelaney I get the curiosity factor.  I get the learn-by-pushing-on-boundaries mentality.  That's why I'm only being partially judgy.  However, Pandas is super good for certain tasks and clearly inefficient for some other tasks.  I've seen people shoehorn tasks into a pandas dataframe that should have been executed in another way.  This may be one of those cases, which is why I ask.

Comment: @piRSquared `DataFrame` explicitely accepts general `object` as values, just like `numpy`. Processing is certainly less efficient than with numerical types, and you personnally may not have a use for it, but calling this an edge case is perhaps a stretch.

Comment: I mean, I'm not mad about it.  But it is my opinion that using classes as index values is somewhere close to an edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error dump:

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2869     def __getitem__(self, key):
   2870         key = lib.item_from_zerodim(key)
-> 2871         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
   2872 
   2873         if is_hashable(key):
```

Pandas sees that `A` is callable, and try to apply the function on the index, similar to when you have:

```
df2.set_index('foo').loc[lambda x: x.index == A]
```

which works. In your case though, `A()` doesn't share the same signature as what `loc` is expecting of a function, that is taking 1 argument for each index.

The code above is a workaround. But I'd like to echo @piRSquared as to why you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In general, pandas index labels have to be hashable, which classes are. However the issue here is that pandas [accepts callables when indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-callable), passing the callable the DataFrame being indexed and using the result to index, and classes are callable. This means that when passing a class to `.loc`, it is called (constructed) with the DataFrame as the sole argument. Short of some weird hack where you remove `__init__` from your class object, or construct some non-callable object that hashes and compares equal to your class (please don't do either of these), this just won't work.